# jquery ScrollTo menu external URL link

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have a problem with a jquery menu. I want one of the the menu links to go to an external site and not a frame within the slides. At present is just opens a blank frame on TEST3.

How would I get it to open an external URL within the same page?

There is a test page located here to understand the issue. http://www.vendvalor.com

```
<section class="content">
            <nav class="main-menu big">
                <a data-id="Test1" href="javascript:void(0)">Test1</a>
                <a data-id="Test2" href="javascript:void(0)">Test2</a>
                <a data-id="Test3" href="http://www.google.com">Test3</a>
                <a data-id="Test4" href="javascript:void(0)">Test4</a>                    
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same problem.. 
Got the solution

```
<ul id="nav">
<li class="current"><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
<li><a href="http://google.com" class="external">Some other link</a></li>
```

The custom.js is

```
  $('#nav').onePageNav({
filter: ':not(.external)'});
```

It worked.. Via: https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav